# In c# mongodb driver how to set dateOnly in serializer to nullable datetime object?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a model with a property (let's say it's called `X`) of type `DateTime?`.
I want to set like `[BsonDateTimeOptions(DateOnly = true)]` but using the class mapper in mongo c# driver like:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyModel>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.X).SetSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer(dateOnly: true));
});
```

But for some reason, I'm getting an error because the property is `Nullable`, for normal `DateTime` type it works properly.

Why I need this because I need to save the value of `X` as date only without timezone.

I already tried to build custom serializer but I'm getting an error when deserializing saying:

> ReadBsonType can only be called when State is Type, not when State is
>   Value

And here's the custom serializer:

```
public class DateTimeNullableSerialzier : DateTimeSerializer, IBsonSerializer
{
    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Null)
            return null;

        return base.Deserialize(context, args);
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        if (value is null)
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
        else
            base.Serialize(context, args, (DateTime)value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, how I implemented the serializer was the problem, after doing some fixes it became usable for any nullable DateTime property (DateTime?) and accept the same constructor params as in `DateTimeSerializer` (but will not work for DateTime types, for some reason):

```
public class DateTimeNullableSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
    public Type ValueType { get; }
    private DateTimeSerializer dateTimeSerializer;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer()
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc, BsonType.DateTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateOnly">if set to <c>true</c> [date only].</param>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer(bool dateOnly)
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(dateOnly);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateOnly">if set to <c>true</c> [date only].</param>
    /// <param name="representation">The representation.</param>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer(bool dateOnly, BsonType representation)
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(dateOnly, representation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="representation">The representation.</param>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer(BsonType representation)
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc, representation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kind">The kind.</param>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer(DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(kind, BsonType.DateTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:DateTimeNullableSerializer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kind">The kind.</param>
    /// <param name="representation">The representation.</param>
    public DateTimeNullableSerializer(DateTimeKind kind, BsonType representation)
    {
        ValueType = typeof(DateTime?);
        dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(kind, representation);
    }

    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Null)
        {
            context.Reader.ReadNull();
            return null;
        }

        return dateTimeSerializer.Deserialize(context, args);
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        if (value is null)
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
        else
            dateTimeSerializer.Serialize(context, args, (DateTime)value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone's reading this and has the same issue, there is actually a way to do this without implementing your own serializer. This is with the 2.x version of the driver, though.

By default, mongo will use `NullableSerializer<T>` for your `DateTime?` field, but the default doesn't have dateOnly set. However, `NullableSerializer<T>` just wraps a normal serializer for the `<T>` type, and there is a way to give it your own instance that you have configured to use dateOnly:

```
var dateSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(dateOnly: true);
var nullableDateOnlySerializer = new NullableSerializer<DateTime>().WithSerializer(dateSerializer);
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyModel>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.X).SetSerializer(nullableDateOnlySerializer);
});
```